# Trying to iterate through multiple lists within one dict

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, iteration

I've got a dict full of various lists that I need to iterate through simultaneously. The intent is to create a string full of comma separated values as columns, but I just can't quite get it right.

The closest I've got so far is:

```
    self.headers = ''
    self.body = ''
    self.headers_temp = ''
    self.body_temp = {}
    self.body_temp1 = {}
    self.body_temp2 = ''
    # comma separated headers
    for key in sorted(self.hist_data):
        self.headers_temp += ',' + key
        self.body_temp[key] = str(self.hist_data[key]).strip('[]')
    print'Headers Temp: ', self.headers_temp, '\n'
    print'Body Temp: ', self.body_temp, '\n'
    for key in self.body_temp:
        self.body_temp1[key] = self.body_temp[key].split(', ')
    print'Body Temp 1: ', self.body_temp1, '\n'
    for key in self.body_temp1:
        for string in self.body_temp1[key]:
            self.body_temp2 += ',\n' + str(string).strip('[]')       
    print'Body Temp 2: ', self.body_temp2, '\n'
    if self.headers == '':
        # dont include the leading ','
        self.headers = self.headers_temp[1:]
    if self.body == '':
        # dont include the leading ',\n'    
        self.body = self.body_temp2[2:]
    print'Headers: ', self.headers, '\n'
    print'Body: ', self.body, '\n'
    service.write_file('myTrades_'+ service.time_to_string(service.system_time, '%Y-%m-%d'), self.headers + '\n' + self.body, mode='overwrite')
```

Output:

```
Init has started...

Start has started... 2018-10-31 09:30:00.000000

Time:  ['2018-10-30 15:55', '2018-10-30 15:56', '2018-10-30 15:57', '2018-10-30 15:58', '2018-10-30 15:59'] 

Open:  [34.729999542236328, 34.654998779296875, 34.685001373291016, 34.679901123046875, 34.724998474121094] 

Headers Temp:  ,open,time 

Body Temp:  {'open': '34.729999542236328, 34.654998779296875, 34.685001373291016, 34.679901123046875, 34.724998474121094', 'time': "'2018-10-30 15:55', '2018-10-30 15:56', '2018-10-30 15:57', '2018-10-30 15:58', '2018-10-30 15:59'"} 

Body Temp 1:  {'open': ['34.729999542236328', '34.654998779296875', '34.685001373291016', '34.679901123046875', '34.724998474121094'], 'time': ["'2018-10-30 15:55'", "'2018-10-30 15:56'", "'2018-10-30 15:57'", "'2018-10-30 15:58'", "'2018-10-30 15:59'"]} 

Body Temp 2:  ,
34.729999542236328,
34.654998779296875,
34.685001373291016,
34.679901123046875,
34.724998474121094,
'2018-10-30 15:55',
'2018-10-30 15:56',
'2018-10-30 15:57',
'2018-10-30 15:58',
'2018-10-30 15:59' 

Headers:  open,time 

Body:  34.729999542236328,
34.654998779296875,
34.685001373291016,
34.679901123046875,
34.724998474121094,
'2018-10-30 15:55',
'2018-10-30 15:56',
'2018-10-30 15:57',
'2018-10-30 15:58',
'2018-10-30 15:59'
```

As you can see I end up with what will translate into one long column of data, rather than having each list added onto the same row essentially. How can I get this so that it takes one value from each key before adding in my line breaks?

My current output is above. As you can see I'm starting with Time and Open which are lists in a dictionary of historical data. I am then trying to find a way to "zip" the two lists together so that I take the first value of each list before moving onto the the second items.

I'm not sure "zip" is the proper term, or if maybe I'm going to need to pull out every dictionary list out of the dictionary to start.

The end all goal is to utilize a very clunky "file_writer" object that requires a perfectly laid out string of text.

There's got to be a better way than what I'm currently doing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you forgot to add a sample input & expected output. Without this this is a bit difficult to help, although I'm suspecting that you're trying to parse a representation of python objects, which is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I updated the original post so that it shows my output which has as sample of the data as it's passing through my code.

Comment: If you supply a sample input dict, such as a small chunk of the dictionary that you're using we can replicate the output that you've put in the post. I'd recommend using the [strip()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) method for strings to get rid of any unwanted white-space.